# Parallel Matrix Manipulation: find eigenvalues and construct list

Tags: parallelization, eigenvalues

I'm having some trouble with the Parallel commands in Mathematica 12.1:

I need to construct a table where its entries are {M, Eigenvalues of X[M]}, where X is a square matrix of dimension N with N big (>3000) and M a parameter. Specifically, I do the following:

```
AbsoluteTiming[BSg1P = Table[M = m;
     {M, #} & /@ (Eigenvalues[N[X]]), {m, -2, 2, 1}];]
```

and I compare with

```
AbsoluteTiming[BSg1P = ParallelTable[M = m;
     {M, #} & /@ (Eigenvalues[N[X]]), {m, -2, 2, 1}];]
```

The computing time is similar for both cases: the difference is around 6 sec. for a total time of 300 sec., which makes no sense if the parallel evaluation is performed. Since I have 2 processors, I would expect half of the time or a considerable fraction for the computing duration.

Am I doing something wrong? Or is there something about parallelization that I don't understand?

On the other hand, if I don't want to use ParallelTable, is there a way to compute the eigenvalues of X[M] in a faster parallel form?

Thanks.

Comment: `AbsoluteTiming` is what you would typically want, since it measures the wall-clock time. `Timing` measures the time spent in the main Wolfram Kernel (not the subkernels), so it's not a good measure for parallelized tasks

Comment: `Eigenvalues` automatically parallelizes if it runs in the main kernel, as long as the matrix is made up of `$MachinePrecision` floating point values or integers, and this probably messes with the timings. Another thing to look out for is caching of the result of `Eigenvalues[N[X]]`.